# how to cancel a server from client with grpc in c#?

Tags: c#, grpc, cancellation, cancellation-token, grpc-c#

I want to cancel a server created in C# from a client written in C#. However, I will not use cancellation tokens for this. I tried to do it with the help of a flag. I wrote a code that sends true when I want to stop sending false while running from the client side. However, when true on the server side, it immediately becomes false again and never exits the while loop. I couldn't solve this problem somehow. can you help me?

```
public override async Task StreamArrays(MyRequest request, IServerStreamWriter<MyResponse> responseStream, ServerCallContext context)
        {
            try
            {
                while (request.IsCancelledRequested == false)
                {
                    MyResponse response = new MyResponse();
                    counter++;
                    response.data = counter;
                    await responseStream.WriteAsync(response);
                    await Task.Delay(15);
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                request.IsCancelledRequested = true;

            }
        }
        //client;

        public async Task SendStreamArray() // for start
        {
            MyRequest request = new MyRequest()
            {

                IsCancelledRequested = false,

            };
            using var responseStreamArray = client.StreamArrays(request);
            await foreach (var response in responseStreamArray.ResponseStream.ReadAllAsync())
            {
                data = response.data;

            }
        }

        public async void StopStream()
        {
            MyRequest request = new MyRequest()
            {

                IsCancelledRequested = true,

            };
            using var responseStreamArray = client.StreamArrays(request);
        }
```

Comment: Include logging to those Methods and you'll probably find that `StreamArrays` will actually be called twice and one of which calls never exits.

Comment: For readability, you could divide your code into client/server side code sections. Independently of that, I feel like you are doing several weird things here: First, why do you set `request.IsCancelledRequested = true;` in the finally block on the server side? This makes no sense, if it is a request coming from the client, and you are checking the incoming request object already in the try block with an infinite while loop, it will already be `true` when you enter the finally block.

Comment: Second, you have an async Task `SendStreamArray` on the client side where it looks like (we cannot know, we do not see your entire client-side code) you start a stream to the server with `client.StreamArrays(request);` and await a response, but then you have another stream initiated in the `StopStream` function, with a single request? You should also be aware that gRPC services are registered as transient per default in C#, meaning that each new request to a service will create a new instance on the server if not configured differently. I think this will result in 2 streams with your code.

Comment: You should provide the full client/server code so people can actually figure out all that is going wrong with your code. It is not possible from what you have provided here, we can just guess what is going on.